# Trying to post and get xml using a proprietary protocol

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to get and post data using xml to a server that uses a proprietary protocol. The only requirements needed are the following in this format STP/00/104/:
STP - the protocol
00 - the version
104 - the bytes or octets

The XML Message follows after. I cant seem to get this to work correctly. When I add in the address bar directly like this
`http://localhost:7777/STP/00/104/<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'><RequestCall><RequestName>GetInfo</RequestName></RequestCall>` nothing happens.

If i add it without the bytes: `http://localhost:7777/STP/00/<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'><RequestCall><RequestName>GetInfo</RequestName></RequestCall>`
I get this response
`STP/00/206/<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?><RequestResponse><RequestName></RequestName><Exception><Code>4</Code><Message>error parsing XML: incorrect declaration</Message></Exception></RequestResponse>`

I figured it was something to do with posting the xml direct in the browsers address bar so I tried to use html and php to get response using this script with no luck as post or get. Also have tried soapui and postman. I did get a cors error and tried to fix it as I have done with soap by adding headers for Access-Control-Allow. I cant figure out what is wrong as I dont do anything with xml normally. I just need to figure out how to get and post to this server using this basic GetInfo which would give me a basis for the rest of my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<script>

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:7777/STP/00/104/");
        var xmlDoc;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            console.log(xmlDoc);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
        var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'><RequestCall><RequestName>GetInfo</RequestName></RequestCall>";
        xmlhttp.send(xml);
    </script>
```

Comment: So you want us to guess how unknown proprietary protocol works?

Comment: More like make suggestions on ways to approach this. In the api  it does not talk about the intial connection other than the requirement I stated. Not knowing much about xml I figure its the way I am trying to make the requests that is the issue.